# Preserve aspect ratio using div

Tags: html, css, sass

**TL;DR**
The `square` class should be a square in all testcases.

The following html includes three testcases.
All testcases contain a flex-box which holds three divs. The div in the middle has a `square` class and (as the name suggests) should be a square in all testcases. The `square` should fill up as much space of the container as possible, but shouldn't exceed it of course.

I already found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css), but it fails on the second and third testcase.

The solution shouldn't include javascript if possible and shouldn't use `aspect-ratio` if possible, because it has bad browser support currently.

Any help is gratefully appreciated.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/pastel-bucket/pen/abqVwBa)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: red;
}

.simple {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.square {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!-- 1. Testcase -->
<div class="container" style="width: 200px; height: 400px">
  <div class="simple">Hello</div>
  <div class="square">World</div>
  <div class="simple">Hello</div>
</div>

<!-- 2. Testcase -->
<div class="container" style="width: 400px; height: 200px">
  <div class="simple">Hello</div>
  <div class="square">World</div>
  <div class="simple">Hello</div>
</div>

<!-- 3. Testcase -->
<div class="container" style="width: 200px; height: 200px">
  <div class="simple">Hello</div>
  <div class="square">World</div>
  <div class="simple">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Comment: how can it be possible when your explicitly setting `height` and `width`!!

Comment: I specified the `width` and `height` of the testcase containers just for demonstrational purposes, but the `width` and `height` of the `square` div isn't explicitly set.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need to support the deprecated IE you can use `aspect-ratio`:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: red;
}

.simple {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.square {
  background-color: yellow;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- 1. Testcase -->
<div class="container" style="width: 200px; min-height: 400px">
  <div class="simple">Hello</div>
  <div class="square">World</div>
  <div class="simple">Hello</div>
</div>

<!-- 2. Testcase -->
<div class="container" style="width: 400px; min-height: 200px">
  <div class="simple">Hello</div>
  <div class="square">World</div>
  <div class="simple">Hello</div>
</div>

<!-- 3. Testcase -->
<div class="container" style="width: 200px; min-height: 200px">
  <div class="simple">Hello</div>
  <div class="square">World</div>
  <div class="simple">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time and giving an answer. I forgot to mention in my initial request, that the `square` div should take up as much space as possible without exceeding the container. I edited my request to include this information.

Just setting the `aspect-ratio` would keep the square small.

Comment: then just give the element a width of 100%; which will make them resize to fill the width. However you need to change then the `height` of the containign parent to `min-height`. Alternativly you can also use the fixed height in combination with `flex-grow` on the square.

Answer (score 1):

To make you `.square` element to keep correct aspect ratio without `aspect-ratio` prop, you could use `pseudo elements`, see:

Also, if you don't want to use `grid` approach, you can make this container `relative` and it's child span element - `absolute` with correct positioning if needed.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: red;
}

.simple {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.square {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'content';
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
}

/* place text content and square pseudo el. to same cell */
.square:before,
.square > span {
  grid-area: content;
}

.square:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%; /* make it square */
}
```

```html
<!-- 1. Testcase -->
<div class="container" style="width: 200px; min-height: 400px">
  <div class="simple">Hello</div>
  <div class="square"><span>World</span></div>
  <div class="simple">Hello</div>
</div>

<!-- 2. Testcase -->
<div class="container" style="width: 400px; min-height: 200px">
  <div class="simple">Hello</div>
  <div class="square"><span>World</span></div>
  <div class="simple">Hello</div>
</div>

<!-- 3. Testcase -->
<div class="container" style="width: 200px; min-height: 200px">
  <div class="simple">Hello</div>
  <div class="square"><span>World</span></div>
  <div class="simple">Hello</div>
</div>
```